# Is there a way to reset Windows' timeGetTime value (time elapsed since Windows started) programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, assembly

In all releases after Windows 7, shutdowns and restarts usually perform a fast boot, and are not considered "full" shut down.

[How to Perform a Full Shutdown in Windows 10](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-perform-a-full-shutdown.html)

In Windows' Win32 API, there's a function called [`timeGetTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timegettime), which returns a DWORD representing the time elapsed since Windows booted up.

The variable this function returns only resets after a full shutdown.

Is there a way to programmatically reset this value to 0? I'm specifically trying to do this in my C# application, but any language is acceptable as it can be converted to C#.

Comment: Write a driver, then call KeBugCheck(), or ,without a driver, ExitWindowsEx() with ExwReboot() :)

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Yeah but the question is if there's a way to reset that value without shutting down, programmatically.

Comment: There isn't, this could result in security issues because other apps might rely on this. This is a global variable. Why do you want to reset it anyway?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I have a game server, and the game enters a bugged state when windows has been up for more than 24.8 days (maximum int value in milliseconds). People basically have godmode because of that. And I want to save them the inconvenience of doing a full shutdown, and reset the value in the game's launch instead.

Comment: Since it is your application, you can just wrap `timeGetTime` in a function that will handle the reset. Though, fixing the bug is probably easier in the long run.

Comment: `timeGetTime` returns the amount of time since Windows was started, so it would make no sense for there to be a means to reset it programmatically. That would break the documented purpose of the function itself, clearly. The way to reset it is to restart Windows. You should fix your game instead.

Comment: @FightRay like Michael says, it would be very dangerous to mess around with the timer, as other apps may also rely on it. But why is your game relying on the system uptime to begin with? Why does it care how long Windows has been running? If you really need that, consider using [`GetTickCount64()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64) instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have a game server, therefore it is not my game. I only coded the server side to emulate it. The client itself is encrypted and I don't have the source code for it. So I have to invent something to fix this issue.

Comment: Is the bug in the client or the sever?  You really need to edit your question so that it describes your actual problem in detail.  As the comments make it clear, the answer to your question as asked is "no".

Comment: @RossRidge The bug is in the client which I'm unable to edit, and it happens because timeGetTime overflows after windows has been up for 24.9 days. If only I could somehow intercept the client's calls to timeGetTime API and use a different method like GetTickCount64....

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish here that requires the counter to be reset to 0?

To answer your question, NO. There is no way to programmatically reset the value to 0. And even if you accomplish this by writing some hack driver (since time counter is protected entity under Windows or for that matter any other OS), you will see several undesirable sideaffects and most likely will cause an immediate watchdog timer bugcheck under windows. Every OS guarantees that time counter will only move forward and a lot of OS components take this fact for granted.

Comment: Then I need to think of a way to solve this issue. If you want to know what I'm trying to accomplish, please read the post's comments.

Comment: @FightRay Since it's too late to change your question now that it's been answered, you'll need to post a new question asking about your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're asking to solve this to solve the Clock Overrun bug in FutureLegends, you could use Detours (or EasyHook as you use C#) to hook `timeGetTime()` and `GetTickCount()`, rather than do this globally

Comment: Hey Shavit, thank you for the answer. But, can you please elaborate? The game is obviously packed and all you can see is either c pseudo code or assembly. Also, timeGetTime is already hooked, so what do you mean by hooking locally? And what does it have to do with GetTickCount? is your proposal to swap between them? If so, how would you do such a thing? I'm using C# as an external application that launches the game (which is written in C++ but there's no source code for it).